# Define formulae in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to use Coq to define the following operator:
[image]

where formulae P and Q has 8 variables

[image]

For simplicity, we can regard each type of the variables as **nat**. However, I have no idea how to translate this operator in Coq. The operator **s/tr** denotes the substitute.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your notation. What is the little black dot after the `f` in the definition?

Comment: I'd bet that it means "such that". In that case that would be a pretty standard definition `P s t tt f /\ Q s t tt f` using the built-in logic, but depending on what you are doing you may want fancier, shallower schemes!

Comment: @ejgallego, according to the question P and Q have 8 variables (parameters), however the substitution is only providing 5 of these. Are `P` and `Q` a tuple of 8 "boolean" variables?

Comment: P and Q look like standard predicates, given a type `V`, then `P, Q : V -> V -> V -> V -> Prop`.

Comment: @TiagoCogumbreiro, because I ignore the other variables, the complete predicates should be `P t1 t tr1 s ttr1 tt flag1 f` and `Q t t2 s tt2 tt ttr2 f flag2` according to the order of the variables above.

Comment: Do you need the operator to be defined on a language embedded into Coq (using an expression datatype) or would it suffice to define it on two Coq predicates(as done when using a deep embedding)?